# Wine can't run 32bit windows programs

Tags: linux, debian, wine, opengl

I'm having an issue with wine as it can run 64 bit windows programs but not 32 bit. I tried to install utorrent which is 32 bit and wine returns this...

```
abhirup@debian:~/Downloads$ wine ./uTorrent.exe 
000f:err:service:process_send_command receiving command result timed out
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"winebus" failed to start: 1053
0032:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0xaeff0c (nil)): stub
0032:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 6795E768, 0084AB78, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 00000000, 0x00000000
0032:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 6795E768
0032:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 6795E768, 0083A9E8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, 00000000, 0x00000000
0032:fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 6795E768
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  170
  Current serial number in output stream:  174
```

now I searched for the two lines "libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found" and "libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast" on google and I understood thet libGl is a openGL lib that wine uses to display something on the screen and libGL has two components a 32 bit and a 64 bit.

I'm on debian 10, using a Nvidia 450.80.02 linux driver with a RTX 2060 gpu and the libGL files are located at:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 (64 bit)
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 (32 bit)
```

below are the symbolic links to those libs:

```
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1->/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1->/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

So having confirmed that there is a 32 bit lib in my system, I can't figure out how to know which 32 bit openGL lib wine is trying to use to run a 32 bit program, and how to change that as I'm guessing that lib is not above one. Also I'm noticing the symlink "tree" structure for the 32 bit and 64 bit libs are not same. So is that causing the problem?

Can anyone know how to fix that, or advice me some other things to get wine to work for 32 bit?

Comment: why do that when there are already lots of torrent clients on Linux

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `wine` installed in the 32bit flavor? Check in your package manager, if you have `wine32` installed.
You might have to add the architecture (`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`) to your system, update the package lists (`sudo apt update`) and install wine32 (`sudo apt install wine32`).

To install/run the 32bit windows program, you will have to create a new wine prefix based on wine32 and install the program there.
They have a section about this [in their FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_create_a_32_bit_wineprefix_on_a_64_bit_system.3F). The essence of it is:

> `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=path_to_wineprefix winecfg`
>
> (use the actual path to the wineprefix)
>
> Do not use an existing directory for the new wineprefix: Wine must create it.

Then install µTorrent there.